# XML import to PHP with empty tags

Tags: php, xml-parsing, domdocument, missing-data

I have a script to import an XML file from a source that I cannot edit (XML file is supplied to me by a third party company and the data changes hourly - they say they can't change the XML file).

Here's a sample of the source:

```
<guns>
<gun id="0021">
<type>Air Pistol</type>
<mechanism>Single Stroke Pneumatic</mechanism>
<model>HW75</model>
<origin>German</origin>
<imageCount>2</imageCount>
<images>
  <image>
    <number>1</number> <fullPath>http://images.mydomain.com/Images/13/1306/13062/001/0021-1.jpg</fullPath>
  </image>
  <image>
    <number>2</number> <fullPath>http://images.mydomain.com/Images/13/1306/13062/001/0021-2.jpg</fullPath>
  </image>
</images>
</gun>

<gun id="0022">
<type>Air Pistol</type>
<mechanism>Single Stroke Pneumatic</mechanism>
<model>HW75</model>
<origin>German</origin>
</gun>
</guns>
```

I can import the fields into PHP, then into Mysql successfully.

However, It stops reading the XML when it realises that the 'fullpath' field doesn't exist.

I have 100 records to import and it stops after the 21st record as record no.22 does not have any images.

Here is my php code:

```
 $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc->load("xmlGuns.xml");
 $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
 $mysql_user = "************";
 $mysql_password = "********";
 $mysql_database = "*********";
 $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
 or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
 mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd)
 or die("Oops some thing went wrong");

 mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE GunTable")
 or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
 mysql_query("ALTER TABLE GunTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")
 or die("Oops some thing went wrong");




  $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('gun');
  for ($i=0; $i<=15000; $i++)
    {
    $type=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('type')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $mechanism=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('mechanism')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $model=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('model')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $origin=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('origin')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $fullPath=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('fullPath')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $insert = "INSERT INTO GunTable (type, mechanism,  model, origin, fullpath) VALUES ('$type', '$mechanism','$model','$origin','$fullpath')";
    $add_member = mysql_query($insert);
    }
```

When it reaches the record with no images, it gives me the following errors after processing record no.21...

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /mydomain.com/import.php on line 31

Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in /mydomain.com/import.php on line 31**

Line 31 starts:   $fullPath=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('fullPath')

Can anyone help! I'm OK with PHP, but this DOMDocument stuff is new for me.

---

Solution:

Phew... I managed to work it out.

```
   if(isset($x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('fullPath')->item(0)->childNodes)) {

   $fullPath=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('fullPath')
   ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

   } else { $fullPath = "No Image"; }
```

Now I have the problem of the URL of the image not inserting into the MySQL database... EEK!

Comment: Can you paste the XML element that fails (and maybe the one before and after)?  It sounds like malformed XML but it could be something else and having the XML will be helpful when trying to debug.

Comment: Thanks.

I managed to add an IF(ISSET( )){ } as the XML was hiding the fields if the record was empty.

I now have the issue of the URL not inserting into the MySQL Table. so now I'm looking into that.